# Google Maps app on Android using jQuery Mobile 1.0a2

Tags: jquery, android, mobile

Is it possible to force a link to open in the Google Maps app on Android using jQuery Mobile 1.0a2. The site in question is http://www.cs.iupui.edu/~migivens/
In my tests, the iPhone does this perfectly with the address simply enclosed in < li > tags. Android fails to recognize the address unless I specifically use the anchor tag and prefix the address with http:// maps.google.com?q=
This is not what I desire because android will only gives a list of available apps capable of opening this link(browser & maps). I would like it to default to the maps app just as the iPhone does. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using a geo URI as specified on this page: http://developer.android.com/guide/appendix/g-app-intents.html

Comment: That worked for android, but it broke the link in my regular browser. In other words, the mobile browser now opens the link using the maps app, but Chrome on my PC does nothing with the link. Is there a way to make it work for both?

Comment: This might not be the best solution, but it should work.  You can detect the user agent of the browser, and if it is from an Android device change the URLs on your site.  This article should help you get started: http://www.gethifi.com/blog/three-ways-to-target-mobile-devices